# awk gensub function usage issue

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

```
cat file

^QciProfilePredefined=qci2$ logicalChannelGroupRef QciTable=default,LogicalChannelGroup=2
EUtranCellTDD=.*-1[123456],UeMeasControl=1,ReportConfigA4=1$ a4ThresholdRsrp -140
```

I want to use gensub() to delete the content before the last comma in $1(also delete the comma),without make influence other column which contains comma.

my code:

```
awk '{$1=gensub(/.*,/,"",1);print}' file
```

output:

```
LogicalChannelGroup=2 logicalChannelGroupRef QciTable=default,LogicalChannelGroup=2
ReportConfigA4=1$ a4ThresholdRsrp -140 a4ThresholdRsrp -140
```

It seems that the ROW 2 content repeated by "4ThresholdRsrp -140".

The output I expected:

```
LogicalChannelGroup=2 logicalChannelGroupRef QciTable=default,LogicalChannelGroup=2
ReportConfigA4=1$ a4ThresholdRsrp -140
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gensub` has 4 arguments `gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])`

you forgot to mention the target, default is `$0` but you need `$1`

`how` argument is used to specify which match to be replaced, for ex: 2nd match or 4th match (like `sed 's///3'`) and also accepts `"g"` or `"G"` to specify all matches

```
awk '{$1=gensub(/.*,/,"",1,$1);print}'
```

you don't need `gensub` here, `sub` will do inplace substitution for first match found. `gsub` will do inplace substitution for all matches found

```
awk '{sub(/.*,/,"",$1);print}'
```